# as.Date() returns NA for only the time part of the datetime string

Tags: r, datetime

In the data frame (`df_pageviews`), I try to convert the following column into datetime format:

```
created_at
2018-03-23 00:51:01
2018-03-23 02:08:37
```

Here is the code I have used (based on [this](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html)):

```
as.Date(df_pageviews$created_at, format = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%H:%m:%s"))
```

However, this code returns the following values: `"2018-03-23" NA, "2018-03-23" NA`

I think the formatting string is correct, but I cannot figure out why it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Write one string format = "string", not format = c("string", "other string"), and check that it's correct (eg, %m cannot match both minute and month)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# replicate the data frame
df_pageviews <- data.frame(
  created_at = c("2018-03-23 00:51:01", "2018-03-23 02:08:37")
)

# convert charachter to POSIXct
df_pageviews$created_at <- strptime(df_pageviews$created_at, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# check the structure
str(df_pageviews)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ created_at: POSIXlt, format: "2018-03-23 00:51:01" "2018-03-23 02:08:37"
```

Comment: my question is why this code would not work when `strptime` is replaced with `as.Date`?

Comment: @renakre, `as.Date` is a date format and not a date/time format, thus `as.Date` only returns the date part of the time. Note: base R does not have time only object, only a date/time, this must contain: year, month, day, hour, minute, sec.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of as.Date(), consider strptime.

Also, be careful of distinguishing %m (month) and %M (minute). You can also specify your timezone https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html

for example:

```
strptime("2018-03-23 00:51:01",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2018-03-23 00:51:01 PDT"
```

Comment: my question is why this code would not work when `strptime` is replaced with `as.Date`?

Comment: Dates and datetimes are structurally different. as.Date will return a date, not a datetime. You can also check out the lubridate package for easier manipulations of datetimes.